# What is "absolute machine code" in .net framework?

Tags: .net, assembly, compilation

I'm trying to understand .net framework architecture and came across the terms "re-locatable machine code" and "absolute machine code". It is said that source code is converted to re-locatable machine code at compile time and this re-locatable machine code is converted to absolute machine code at load time. 
Does this mean re-locatable machine code is nothing but an assembly? Then what is absolute machine code? What is load time? What exactly happens at compile time, load time and runtime/execution time in .net framework architecture? I cannot find a clear distinction for these terminologies.

Comment: It plays (almost) no role in .NET.  Machine code is generated just-in-time and is never moved afterwards.  A feature that is rather important, the jitter and CLR can make code very efficient by hard-coding addresses without having to worry that they'll have to be adjusted.  It matters to unmanaged code, the kind that is compiled on one machine and executes on another.  Such code uses a linker that has to guess at a preferred load address for a DLL.  If that address space is occupied then it has to move the code elsewhere and that might require patching addresses.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a lot of familiarity with .net specifically, but I think I can give you a high-level explanation of what's going on:

- "re-locatable machine code" means it takes your code and compiles it down to a version that is not architecture specific. In case you are not aware, the assembly code needed to run a program can differ from system to system. I'm not sure exactly what this machine code would look like, but I assume they're compiling your code as much as possible.
- "absolute machine code" is the actual code that will run on the system. When the program is loaded (when you run it), it must take the system-agnostic re-locatable machine code and do the last few steps needed to make it run specifically on that system.
- "load time" is, I assume, when you run the program

So when you compile a program, it converts it into some form of byte code that can't actually be run by itself. Then when you run the program, that byte code is converted into actual assembly code that can be run.